# Jquery tabs conflicting with revolution slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, conflict

I am trying to create a page containing revolution slider and a tabs script.

You can find the page here: http://lovebomb.nl/dating

But somehow the scripts are conflicting with one another.

This part of the revolution slider:

```
        var tpj=jQuery;
    tpj.noConflict();

    tpj(document).ready(function() {

    if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal!=undefined)
        tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;

        tpj('.fullwidthbanner').revolution(
            {
                delay:9000,
                startwidth:1024,
                startheight:616,
                onHoverStop:"on",                       // Stop Banner Timet at Hover on Slide on/off
                thumbWidth:100,                         // Thumb With and Height and Amount (only if navigation Tyope set to thumb !)
                thumbHeight:50,
                thumbAmount:3,
                navigationStyle:"round",                // round,square,navbar,round-old,square-old,navbar-old, or any from the list in the docu (choose between 50+ different item), custom
                navigationHAlign:"center",              // Vertical Align top,center,bottom
                navigationVAlign:"top",                 // Horizontal Align left,center,right
                navigationHOffset:0,    
                navigationVOffset:20,
                soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
                soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
                soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
                soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,
                soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
                soloArrowRightValign:"center",
                soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
                soloArrowRightVOffset:0,
                touchenabled:"off",                     // Enable Swipe Function : on/off
                stopAtSlide:1,                          // Stop Timer if Slide "x" has been Reached. If stopAfterLoops set to 0, then it stops already in the first Loop at slide X which defined. -1 means do not stop at any slide. stopAfterLoops has no sinn in this case.
                stopAfterLoops:0,                       // Stop Timer if All slides has been played "x" times. IT will stop at THe slide which is defined via stopAtSlide:x, if set to -1 slide never stop automatic
                hideCaptionAtLimit:0,                   // It Defines if a caption should be shown under a Screen Resolution ( Basod on The Width of Browser)
                hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,               // Hide all The Captions if Width of Browser is less then this value
                hideSliderAtLimit:0,                    // Hide the whole slider, and stop also functions if Width of Browser is less than this value
                fullWidth:"on",
                shadow:0                                //0 = no Shadow, 1,2,3 = 3 Different Art of Shadows -  (No Shadow in Fullwidth Version !)
            });
 });
```

Seems to be conflicting with this part of the tabs script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tabs div').hide();
$('#tabs div:first').show();
$('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
$('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){ 
$('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
$('#tabs div').hide();
$(currentTab).show();
return false;
});
});
```

These scripts are combined in one JS file which can be found here: http://lovebomb.nl/dating/tabs.js

I used this site as a base for the tabs script: http://www.snelgeldonlineverdienen.nl/

The only difference is the jquery and the jquery UI version.
If I use the version of jquery of this page, the revolution slider does not work anymore.

I am already trying to fix the tabs for about 4 hours.

Really could use some help.

Thanks in advance :)

Luuk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of [tabs.js](http://lovebomb.nl/dating/tabs.js) we have the declaration:

```
var tpj=jQuery;
tpj.noConflict();
```

this sets the variable **tpj** to the **jQuery** object, and then puts jQuery into [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

> "Many JavaScript libraries use **$** as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using **$**. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of **$** back to the other library with a call to **$.noConflict()**."

Now that jQuery is in no conflict mode you can no longer use the **$** to access jQuery. So when we run the code at the bottom of tabs.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){ 
    $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

We get the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function"

because **$** no longer references **jQuery**. To access jQuery we must use **jQuery** or **tpj**

if we alter the tabs.js changing **$** to either **jQuery** or **tpj**

```
tpj(document).ready(function(){
    tpj('#tabs div').hide();
    tpj('#tabs div:first').show();
    tpj('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    tpj('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){ 
    tpj('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
    tpj(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
    var currentTab = tpj(this).attr('href'); 
    tpj('#tabs div').hide();
    tpj(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

the code should execute correctly.

Comment: I was really glad to see an answer :) Unfortunately this is not the answer. I tried your code and it still is displaying it the same way. @ceetee thanks for your time anyway, hope you can help me out a little further?

Comment: Hey Luuk, just updated the last code snippet. the $ at the beginning of $(document).ready also needs to be replaced with tpj or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use Latest jQuery library Version( 1.7.1 +)  and Try to modify above code to following and combine both to single file in init.js and place at bottom of all *.js files included in a page.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       if (jQuery.fn.cssOriginal!=undefined)
         jQuery.fn.css = jQuery.fn.cssOriginal;
           jQuery('.fullwidthbanner').revolution({

            delay:9000,
            startwidth:1024,
            startheight:616,
            onHoverStop:"on",        // Stop Banner Timet at Hover on Slide on/off
            thumbWidth:100,        // Thumb With and Height and Amount (only if navigation Tyope set to thumb !)
            thumbHeight:50,
            thumbAmount:3,
            navigationStyle:"round",   // round,square,navbar,round-old,square-old,navbar-old, or any from the list in the docu (choose between 50+ different item), custom
            navigationHAlign:"center",              // Vertical Align top,center,bottom
            navigationVAlign:"top",                 // Horizontal Align left,center,right
            navigationHOffset:0,    
            navigationVOffset:20,
            soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
            soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
            soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
            soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,
            soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
            soloArrowRightValign:"center",
            soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
            soloArrowRightVOffset:0,
            touchenabled:"off",                     // Enable Swipe Function : on/off
            stopAtSlide:1,                          // Stop Timer if Slide "x" has been Reached. If stopAfterLoops set to 0, then it stops already in the first Loop at slide X which defined. -1 means do not stop at any slide. stopAfterLoops has no sinn in this case.
            stopAfterLoops:0,                       // Stop Timer if All slides has been played "x" times. IT will stop at THe slide which is defined via stopAtSlide:x, if set to -1 slide never stop automatic
            hideCaptionAtLimit:0,                   // It Defines if a caption should be shown under a Screen Resolution ( Basod on The Width of Browser)
            hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,               // Hide all The Captions if Width of Browser is less then this value
            hideSliderAtLimit:0,                    // Hide the whole slider, and stop also functions if Width of Browser is less than this value
            fullWidth:"on",
            shadow:0                                //0 = no Shadow, 1,2,3 = 3 Different Art of Shadows -  (No Shadow in Fullwidth Version !)
        });
 });       

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#tabs div').hide();
      jQuery('#tabs div:first').show();
      jQuery('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
      jQuery('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){ 
      jQuery('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
      jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
      var currentTab = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
     jQuery('#tabs div').hide();
     jQuery(currentTab).show();
     return false;
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue while getting a canned html/css/js landing page template to work on Meteor. In my case removing the jquery-1.11.1.min.js and jquery-1.11.1.min.map files from the solution fixed the problem because I already have the latest version installed as a package. Hope this helps a solution searcher in the future.