# JQuery Tabs - Link to a tab from a tab. Works in Chrome, not FF/IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using this plugin for Wordpress http://wordpress.org/plugins/put/ which adds JQuery tabs to posts using a shortcode. I'll have 8-10 unique tab sets on each page and I need a hyperlink in each Tab 1 to link to it's own Tab 4.

The following code works in Chrome desktop/mobile but in Firefox & IE it opens the url javascript: jQuery('a[href=#tabs-1-4]').click() that says [object Object] on the page.

```
<a href="javascript: jQuery('a[href=#tabs-1-4]').click()"><span class="icon-shopping-cartsmall"></span> BUY A LICENSE</a>
```

The plugin already adds unique id's for each tab in a post so having unique id's to link to isn't a problem.

What do I need to use in that hyperlink that will work in all browsers/mobile? I want it to function exactly like it does now in Chrome where no hashtag is added to the url and it just jumps to the 4th tab.

------ **EDIT** -------

Found this code and it seems to work in IE/FF/Chrome! Does this look ok to you experts?

```
<div class="buybutton"><a onclick="$('a[href=#tabs-1-4]').click();"><span class="icon-shopping-cartsmall"></span> BUY A LICENSE</a></div>
```

Comment: I'm thinking I need to use onclick instead but I don't know how to write it into the link.

Comment: Its working in my Firefox.... IE is crappy...

Comment: Yea the new code I added under the edit fixed it. Of course another problem arises, the Buy A License button for the code doesn't work on the Home page.

Works: http://testsite.rockitpro.com/category/beatswithhooks/

Doesn't work: http://testsite.rockitpro.com/

Comment: That reason for that might be because jQuery might not be loaded in the Home Page,that is, its loading only on Posts,Pages and Categories. If you'll see the Javascript console and click on the Buy a License button(in Home Page), you'll see something like `TypeError: $ is not defined`

Comment: I checked the error console and it says "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not an option. onclick" Pretty sure everything loads on all pages though.

Comment: I got the $ is not defined error.... M pretty sure its the jquery not being loaded in it.

Comment: It's the Revolution Slider causing the issue, I just removed it and the Buy A License button works fine on home page. I found this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067465/jquery-tabs-conflicting-with-revolution-slider

Comment: I found an option in the Revolution Slider plugin "JQuery No Conflict Mode" and it needs to be turned OFF if anyone comes across this problem. Thanks for the insight kakashihatake2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This updated code seems to work in Chrome/FF/IE:

```
<div class="buybutton"><a onclick="$('a[href=#tabs-1-4]').click();"><span class="icon-shopping-cartsmall"></span> BUY A LICENSE</a></div>
```