# Cyclone Slider - jQuery Tab Conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tabs, slider

I wanted to put a slider inside a jQuery Tab, but when the jQuery code hides the tabs and shows only the first tab, the slider loses its function (remains hidden).

You can find the tab in the demo page of Kent theme: http://demo.fabthemes.com/kent/
The jQuery code is:

```
    jQuery('#tabs div').hide();
    jQuery('#tabs div:first').show();
    jQuery('#tabs ul.tabnav li:first').addClass('active');

    jQuery('#tabs ul.tabnav li a').click(function(){
    jQuery('#tabs ul.tabnav li').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#tabs div').hide();
    jQuery(currentTab).show();
    jQuery('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('reinit');
    return false;
    });
```

and the Cyclone 2 Slider:

> ```
>    <div tabindex="0" class="cycloneslider cycloneslider-template-standard cycloneslider-width-responsive" id="cycloneslider-gisheh-1" style="max-width:960px">
>           <div class="cycloneslider-slides cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-allow-wrap="true" data-cycle-dynamic-height="off" data-cycle-auto-height="960:400" data-cycle-auto-height-easing="null" data-cycle-auto-height-speed="250" data-cycle-delay="0" data-cycle-easing="" data-cycle-fx="fade" data-cycle-hide-non-active="true" data-cycle-log="false" data-cycle-next="#cycloneslider-gisheh-1 .cycloneslider-next" data-cycle-pager="#cycloneslider-gisheh-1 .cycloneslider-pager" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="false" data-cycle-prev="#cycloneslider-gisheh-1 .cycloneslider-prev" data-cycle-slides="&gt; div" data-cycle-speed="1000" data-cycle-swipe="false" data-cycle-tile-count="7" data-cycle-tile-delay="100" data-cycle-tile-vertical="true" data-cycle-timeout="4000">
>                   <div class="cycloneslider-slide cycloneslider-slide-image">
>                           <img src="http://example.com/img/img1.jpg" alt="" title="" />
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="cycloneslider-slide cycloneslider-slide-image">
>                           <img src="http://example.com/img/img2.jpg" alt="" title="" />
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="cycloneslider-slide cycloneslider-slide-image">
>                           <img src="http://example.com/img/img3.jpg" alt="" title="" />
>                   </div>
>                   <div class="cycloneslider-slide cycloneslider-slide-image">
>                           <img src="http://example.com/img/img4.jpg" alt="" title="" />
>                   </div>
>           </div>
>           <div class="cycloneslider-pager"></div>
>           <a href="#" class="cycloneslider-prev"> <span class="arrow"></span> 
>           </a>
>           <a href="#" class="cycloneslider-next"> <span class="arrow"></span> 
>           </a>
>     </div>
> ```

And this is what I've done so far:
Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067465/jquery-tabs-conflicting-with-revolution-slider). Didn't work for me!
Read [this page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/). Tried destroy, cycle, reinit; none worked.

Hint: The slider is a wordpress plugin. The jQuery tab hides all the parts of the slider (div's and sub divisions), and once it's hidden, it can never get back to life! It have tried outside the tab. The slider shows and once it's hidden (using Inspect Element), it never comes back!
I also have tried other sliders. They come back once the display:none is removed!

What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no way for Cyclone! I had to use Weptile Image Slider Widget.