# Conflict between pages in Jquery easy tabs, trying to solve with jquery noconflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tabs

I have an easy tabs page,with three different pages(TAB1,TAB2,TAB3).

Tab.php

Tab1|Tab2|Tab3

//Tab1 has an slider plugin(with Jquery UI)
//Tab2 has an autocomplete for select list

The conflict come from because two function wants  to use jquery variable.

Two pages contains jquery plugins but with only jquery version(jquery-1.11.1.min.js)

The tabs only works properly(elements showing,jquery methods correctly running) when only one tabs is enabled(just commenting the link).

I use the jquery no conlict to try to solve this problem(before that there was conflict between the main tab page and the invidual page):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">   
 var s = $.noConflict();
</script>
```

So on the sub page(tab1) i use like:

```
s(document).ready(function(){.....}
```

I also try to define a second shortcut(first i try to use the same 's' there too) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">     
var j = $.noConflict();
 var s = $.noConflict();
    </script>
```

to use this at the Tab2 page.It was not a solution for me.Diseable Tab1 and using 'j' also works good.

One more importent thing is the firts downloaded page shown correctly each time,so i know the conflict is becuse of the jquery variable(overwrite it or something like this).

I try to find a solution by my self but i couldn't.Please help me

- Update1:

As i note before i made a lot of research before that:
[Jquery tabs conflicting with revolution slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067465/jquery-tabs-conflicting-with-revolution-slider)

This question is very similar for my problem,but the difference i have more tabs,more conflict so i thought if i use more shortcut it will solve the issue.

- Update2:
  It is more interfering between the plugins than conflict.
  using

  var s = $.noConflict(true);

totally throw awey the full page,even the tabs does not want to work
First the tab.php load,it is using the jquery global variable,
than if i click on Tab1 it is also wants to use the global variable,
After if i click on Tab2 also need jquery variable 
So bumm the interfering is ready

- Update3:
  After a lot of research,i found the problem is not with the noconflict.
  The Tab2(upload.php) page is correctly rendered when i full reload the page.

  ```
  s(document).ready(function(s) {//without the ready it does not rendered even after F5
  ```

  s("#modell").select2(); });

Comment: still not clear why you are using `noConflict`. Are you sure you need to use it? If so why?

Comment: without it the sub pages doesent work(it has other jquery plugins and there is something trouble with the main tabs page and the subs).
So by noconflict i was able to make it work on sub page and the main Tab page

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are trying to load jQuery with a different variable name. I would suggest that you use:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( blah ) {
    //You can now use blah as the jquery method (e.g. blah("#button").click();)
});
```

I've made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/me66st8w/. You can find out more about this in the official documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/.

Comment: and how about this:
blah(function( blah ){//before it was  
//s(document).ready( function() {$(function( $ ){


jvar('#tab-container').easytabs({
animate:false,
});

Comment: No, you have to use the method jQuery until you define it inside 'ready(function(...))' (where ... is the new jQuery function name)

Comment: sorry it was not the soultion i tried a lot.As i wrote in the update3 the page is correctly rendered after refredh(F5)